# Bigcommerce csv format

Tags: csv, bigcommerce

I'm looking for information on setting up a proper csv file for import into the Bigcommerce platform and cannot find the information on their server.

Specifically, how to format the csv file with image url, sku, and category arrays so that they are correctly imported.

Comment: I found the [sample csv file](https://support.mybigcommerce.com/content/article-attachments/bulk-edit-product-import-template.csv) however it lists the product image id, which, if I'm adding a new product I won't have a product image id yet.  Is this field just left blank?

Comment: Yes, you can just omit the image id column entirely if you are importing new products via CSV.